# change image based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help with my javascript and/or jquery. I am a designer and I'm trying to create some cool animation effects. Specifically, based on scroll position, I would like to change an image. the html I am working on:

the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var yPos;
function yScroll(){
yPos = window.pageYOffset;
if(yPos < 20){
    $("#phone").attr("src", "assets/img/phone-right.png");
    } if(yPos < 40) {
      $("#phone").attr("src", "assets/img/phone-front.png");
    } if(yPos > 41){
      $("#phone").attr("src", "assets/img/phone-left.png");
    }
window.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);}
</script>
```

Once again, I am a designer, wanting to achieve some cool effects via javascript and/or jquery. Can anyone help?

Comment: The HTML is missing... Please describe how what you already have isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code you can use

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var containerHeight = $('#container').height();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
       var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollPosition > (containerHeight / 2))
        {
            $('img').attr("src", "http://www.cosplay.com/i/costumes/200/313779.jpg");   
        }
        else if (scrollPosition < (containerHeight / 2))
        {
            $('img').attr("src", "http://www.unikgamer.com/characters/face/ryu-street-fighter-85.jpg"); 
        }

    }) // scroll function

})// end document
```

What I did was to create a container big enough to be scrollable and test the code. Then using .height() I got the height of the container (1200px). Now create a function that gets triggered when the window scrolls using $(window).scroll()

Finally create another variable inside this function that tracks the pixels scrolled using $(window).scrollTop().

If the window scroll is bigger than half size of the container height change the img src attribute to another images.

If the window scroll is smaller than half size of the container height change the img src attribute to the original images. Here is the fiddle. I hope this helps

https://jsfiddle.net/PatoSalazarC/72pg342w/3/